# Cursor disappears when not moving the mouse ubunut 20.04.6

Tags: 20.04, mouse, mouse-pointer

When not moving the mouse/touch-pad the cursor disappears, when I move it it will show up again. if I'm typing on a program and the mouse is hovering over another one when the mouse disappears the focus will change to the second program. Even when I am scrolling the mouse will disappear and stop me from scrolling.

This is a new behavior, been happening for a couple of days now. I tried every solution I could find but nothing solved it so far.